# Nested Task<T> calls without async/await

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

This is kind of related to the following post: [Why use Async/await all the way down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808915/why-use-async-await-all-the-way-down)

I am curious what happens in the following scenario:

Updated due to comment:

```
async Task FooAsync()
{
    await Func1();
    // do other stuff
}

Task Func1()
{
    return Func2();
}

async Task Func2()
{
    await tcpClient.SendAsync();
    // do other stuff
}
```

Does this whole process becomes a blocking call?  Or because Func1() is actually awaited on, the UI can go and work on something else?  Ultimately is it necessary to add the async/await on Func1()?  I've played around with it but I don't actually notice any difference, hence the question.  Any insight would be great, thanks!

Comment: Does not compile, missing return statement in Func1()

Answer (score 3):

`Async` and `await` are just compiler features.

Without `await` calling async method will cause it to execute synchronous (blocking) way..

When you are writing `await` all code bellow `await` is wrapped in `Task.ContinueWith()` Method by compiler automaticly, this means that when task is finished code below is executed later

```
public async Task<int> method2(){
  return Task.FromResult(1);
}

public void method1(){
  await method2()
  Console.WriteLine("Done");
}
```

will translate something like :

```
  public Task<int> method2(){
      return Task.FromResult(1);
    }

    public void method1(){
      method2().ContinueWith(x => {
        Console.WriteLine("Done");
      });
    }
```

Comment: Note: It is not as simple as just a `ContinueWith`, [here is a old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573625/how-does-async-await-not-block/20573825#20573825) where I explained the same concept in more detail if you want to see

Comment: And, if you don't use `async-await` it woun't block.

Answer (score 0):

The only problem of not making `Func1` and `async` method and not `await`ing `Func2` in it is that any thrown exception won't show `Func1`.

The bottom line is that `await` works on *awaitables* and `Task`/`Task<T>` are *awaitables*.