# C# async/await - UI thread vs. other threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await

I'm imagining that if I write code like [this](http://www.itwriting.com/blog/4913-a-simple-example-of-async-and-await-in-c-5.html):

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.button1.Enabled = false; 
   var someTask = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => slowFunc(1, 2)); 
   await someTask;  
   this.label1.Text = "Result: " + someTask.Result.ToString(); 
   this.button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

That the compiler actually does this:

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   this.button1.Enabled = false; 
   var someTask = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(() => slowFunc(1, 2)); 
   save_context_including_someTask();
   when_someTask_completes(post_message_into_queue(run_afterStuff()));
}
private void afterStuff()
{
   restore_context_including_someTask();
   this.label1.Text = "Result: " + someTask.Result.ToString(); 
   this.button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

So it uses the (normally hidden) message queue to execute the code after the "await" in a synchronous manner (it doesn't interrupt anything I'm already doing on the UI thread).  Yes?

But then the implementation of async/await must be rather different, if I run them in a thread besides the main UI thread, where there isn't a message queue.

Since there isn't any way for the compiler to know what the "next thing" is in my non-UI thread, when it hits an "await" it must just .... stop and wait?

To make a long question shorter, is await synchronous in a non-UI thread?

Comment: No it is not syncronous, when you are not on the UI thread `save_context_including_someTask()` will grab the default [`SynchronizationContext`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) which will make `post_message_into_queue(`  use the ThreadPool queue.

Comment: See [this old answer of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573625/how-does-async-await-not-block/20573825#20573825) which shows a more realistic conversion of what async/await code gets turned in to, going from a simple abstraction all the way down to the actual code the compiler generates.