# How to implement the OnCompleted method of a custom awaiter correctly?

Tags: c#, async-await

I have a custom awaitable type and the problem is that the continuation resumes on a different thread, which causes problems in UIs such as WinForms/WPF/MVC/etc:

```
private MyAwaitable awaitable;

private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    awaitable = new MyAwaitable(false);
    progressBar1.Visible = true;

    // A regular Task can marshal the execution back to the UI thread
    // Here ConfigureAwait is not available and I don't know how to control the flow
    var result = await awaitable;

    // As a result, here comes the usual "Cross-thread operation not valid" exception
    // A [Begin]Invoke could help but regular Tasks also can handle this situation
    progressBar1.Visible = false;
}

private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) => awaitable.Finish();
```

Here is the `MyAwaitable` class:

```
public class MyAwaitable
{
    private volatile bool finished;
    public bool IsFinished => finished;
    public MyAwaitable(bool finished) => this.finished = finished;
    public void Finish() => finished = true;
    public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter() => new MyAwaiter(this);
}
```

And the problematic custom awaiter:

```
public class MyAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly MyAwaitable awaitable;
    private readonly SynchronizationContext capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public MyAwaiter(MyAwaitable awaitable) => this.awaitable = awaitable;
    public bool IsCompleted => awaitable.IsFinished;

    public int GetResult()
    {
        var wait = new SpinWait();
        while (!awaitable.IsFinished)
            wait.SpinOnce();
        return new Random().Next();
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {            
        // continuation(); // This would block the UI thread

        // Task constructor + Start was suggested by the references I saw,
        // Results with Task.Run/Task.Factory.StartNew are similar.
        var task = new Task(continuation, TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);

        // If executed from a WinForms app, we have a WinFormsSyncContext here,
        // which is promising, still, it does not solve the problem.
        if (capturedContext != null)
            capturedContext.Post(state => task.Start(), null);
        else
            task.Start();
    }
}
```

I suspect that my `OnCompleted` implementation is not quite correct.

I tried to dig into the `ConfiguredTaskAwaiter` returned by the `Task.ConfigureAwait(bool).GetAwaiter()` method and could see that the black magic happens in a `SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation` class but that is an internal one, along with lot of other internally used types. Is there a way to refactor my `OnCompleted` implementation to work as expected?

**Update**: *Note to downvoters*: I know I do improper things in `OnCompleted`, that's why I ask. If you have concerns about quality (or anything else) please leave a comment and help me to improve the question so I also can help you to highlight the problem better. Thanks.

*Note 2*: I know I could use a workaround with a `TaskCompletionSource<TResult>` and its regular `Task<TResult>` result but I would like to understand the background. *This is the only motivation. Pure curiosity.*

**Update 2**: Notable references I investigated:

How awaiter works:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/20573825/5114784
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12661431/5114784

Some implementations:

- https://marcinotorowski.com/2018/03/13/tap-await-anything-not-only-tasks/ - wrong, blocks caller thread until `GetResult` returns
- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything - just calls other awaiters
- https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-2-awaitable-awaiter-pattern - similar to mine, has the same issue

Comment: You need to capture the synchronization context before running your awaitable.

Comment: Even if I capture it in the constructor, the result is the same.

Comment: Why are you using the Task constructor and why are you using those arguments in it?

Comment: @PauloMorgado: The `continuation` is the delegate I want to execute. `LongRunning` option is a hint to the `TaskScheduler` and indicates the execution can last long. The default scheduler implementation creates a new `Thread` for such tasks instead of using the `ThreadPool` (but actually can be ignored). Why ctor: I guess you are asking why not `Task.Run` or `Task.Factory.StartNew`. It's because I don't need to wait until the `Task` is scheduled and its state changes to Running after starting.

Comment: Have you seen any implementation of an awaiter that even resembles with this one? Have you tried to just get rid of all that Task code in the awaiter and just post or execute the action?

Comment: @PauloMorgado: No, I just saw plainly wrong implementations (eg. calling continuation directly, like here: https://marcinotorowski.com/2018/03/13/tap-await-anything-not-only-tasks/) or implementations where usually other awaiters are called: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/01/13/await-anything. This one uses `Task.Start` as mine: https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/understanding-c-sharp-async-await-2-awaitable-awaiter-pattern. So no idea how to implement it correctly without using other awaiters, hence the question.

Comment: @Nkosi: Pure curiosity. :) Not for reinvention but as I've written in the description I want to understand the background. But as I see from the downvotes, this mentality is not quite appreciated. :P In a business code the "workaround" would be perfect for me.

Comment: @taffer Ok noted. I'll remove my previous comment to avoid attracting negative reviews.

Comment: No need to create and schedule another task for the continuation.Either execute the continuation directly, or post it to the captured context. Change all occurences of ```task.Start()``` to ```continuation()``` and you are done.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis: No, changing `task.Start()` to `continuation()` blocks the UI thread so that is definitely wrong. It works only if you finish the task from another thread and if there is no cross-thread issue (eg. using a timer in a console app where there is no synchronization context, like in Paulo's answer). But Ivan already provided the correct answer and I also added one, which simulates even the `ConfigureAwait` behavior.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The MSDN explanation for [`OnCompleted`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.inotifycompletion.oncompleted?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion.OnCompleted);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.7.1);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=netframework-4.7.2) method is:

> Schedules the continuation action that's invoked when the instance completes.

Hence neither of the implementations of the `OnCompleted` is "correct", because the `awaiter` shouldn't execute the passed delegate during that call if the `awaitable` is not already complete, but register it to be executed when the `awaitable` completes.

The only unclear is what the method should do if the `awaitable` is already complete at the time the method is called (although the compiler generated code does not call it in such case) - ignore the continuation delegate or execute. According to the `Task` implementation, it should be the later (execute).

Of course there are exceptions of the rule (hence the word *"correct"*). For instance, the `YieldAwaiter` specifically always returns `IsCompleted == false` to force calling it's `OnCompleted` method, which immediately  schedules the passed delegate on the thread pool. But "normally" you won't do that.

Usually (as with the standard `Task` implementation) the `awaitable` will perform the operation, provide the result, the wait mechanism, and will maintain/execute the continuations. Their `awaiters` are usually `struct`s holding the reference to the shared `awaitable` (along with continuation options when needed) and will delegate the `GetResult` and `OnCompleted` method calls to the shared `awaitable`, and specifically for `OnCompleted` passing the continuation delegate as well as options to the `awaitable` internal method responsible for registering/executing them. The "configurable" `awaitable`s will simply hold the shared `awaitable` plus the options and simply pass them to the created `awaiter`s.

Since in your example the waiting and result are provided by the `awaiter`, the `awaitable` can simply provide completion event:

```
public class MyAwaitable
{
    private volatile bool finished;
    public bool IsFinished => finished;
    public event Action Finished;
    public MyAwaitable(bool finished) => this.finished = finished;
    public void Finish()
    {
        if (finished) return;
        finished = true;
        Finished?.Invoke();
    }
    public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter() => new MyAwaiter(this);
}
```

and the `awaiter`s would subscribe on it:

```
public class MyAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly MyAwaitable awaitable;
    private int result;

    public MyAwaiter(MyAwaitable awaitable)
    {
        this.awaitable = awaitable;
        if (IsCompleted)
            SetResult();

    }
    public bool IsCompleted => awaitable.IsFinished;

    public int GetResult()
    {
        if (!IsCompleted)
        {
            var wait = new SpinWait();
            while (!IsCompleted)
                wait.SpinOnce();
        }
        return result;
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (IsCompleted)
            {
                continuation();
                return;
            }
        var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        awaitable.Finished += () =>
        {
            SetResult();
            if (capturedContext != null)
                capturedContext.Post(_ => continuation(), null);
            else
                continuation();
        };
    }

    private void SetResult()
    {
        result = new Random().Next();
    }
}
```

When `OnCompleted` is called, first we check if we are complete. If yes, we simply execute the passed delegate and return. Otherwise, we capture the synchronization context, subscribe on the `awaitable` completion event, and inside that event execute the action either via the captured synchronization context or directly.

Again, in the real life scenarios the `awaitable` should perform the real work, provide the result and maintain continuation actions, while `awaiter`s should only register the continuation actions, eventually abstracting the continuation execution strategy - directly, via captured synchronization context, via thread pool etc.

Comment: Wow, this was really enlightening. This was the missing information I couldn't find anywhere. The MSDN is really tight-lipped about this, without a single example, and the enormous amount of other references just never cover this scenario (at least I couldn't find anything). Promise is promise, have your bounty (I'm not allowed to give the award for a while). Until then take my upvote and the confirmation as the accepted answer.

Comment: Absolutely agree - MSDN should provide a good explanation of what is expected by the implementers, as well as the purpose of each player, method and when it is called, rather than simple summary from the link. Looks like they keep the "advanced" stuff only for their implementations :)

Answer (score 0):

**This proves that the continuation runs on the captured context**:

```
public class MyAwaitable
{
    private volatile bool finished;
    public bool IsFinished => finished;
    public MyAwaitable(bool finished) => this.finished = finished;
    public void Finish() => finished = true;
    public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter() => new MyAwaiter(this);
}

public class MyAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly MyAwaitable awaitable;
    private readonly SynchronizationContext capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;

    public MyAwaiter(MyAwaitable awaitable) => this.awaitable = awaitable;
    public bool IsCompleted => awaitable.IsFinished;

    public int GetResult()
    {
        SpinWait.SpinUntil(() => awaitable.IsFinished);
        return new Random().Next();
    }

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        if (capturedContext != null) capturedContext.Post(state => continuation(), null);
        else continuation();
    }
}

public class MySynchronizationContext : SynchronizationContext
{
    public override void Post(SendOrPostCallback d, object state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Posted to synchronization context");
        d(state);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new MySynchronizationContext());

        var awaitable = new MyAwaitable(false);

        var timer = new Timer(_ => awaitable.Finish(), null, 100, -1);

        var result = await awaitable;

        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Posted to synchronization context
124762545
```

But you are not posting the continuation to the synchronization context.

You're posting scheduling the execution of the continuation on another thread.

The scheduling runs on the synchronization context but continuation itself doesn't. Thus your problems.

You can read [this](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/category/eduasync/) to understand how it works.

Comment: Yes, I suspected something similar, though I still don't know how I should've done this. Now I'm using a `TaskCompletionSource` to achieve the same goal but if I will have time maybe I go for it again. Thank you for the link - I regularly read Jon Skeet's materials so I don't even understand how I didn't find this. I will go through it once I have enough time.

Comment: This is the answer that solves the actual problem in the code presented by the op

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Originally I put this answer as a summary in the end of the question after @IvanStoev gave the correct answer (many thanks for the enlightenment). Now I extracted that part into a real answer.

---

So based on Ivan's answer here is a small summary containing the missing parts, which I believe should be in the documentations. The example below mimics also the `ConfigureAwait` behavior of `Task`.

**1. The test app**

A WinForms app (could be other single-threaded UI as well) with a `ProgressBar` and 3 `Button` controls: one button simply starts an async operation (and a progress bar), the others finish it either in the UI thread or in a foreign thread.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        progressBar.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Marquee;
        progressBar.Visible = false;
    }

    private MyAwaitable awaitable;

    private async void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        awaitable = new MyAwaitable();
        progressBar.Visible = true;
        var result = await awaitable; //.ConfigureAwait(false); from foreign thread this throws an exception
        progressBar.Visible = false;
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }

    private void buttonStopUIThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        awaitable.Finish(new Random().Next());

    private void buttonStopForeignThread_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) =>
        Task.Run(() => awaitable.Finish(new Random().Next()));
 }
```

**2. The custom awaitable class**

As opposed to the original example in the question, here the awaitable class itself contains the continuation, which is invoked once the execution is finished. So an awaiter can just request to schedule the continuation for later execution.

And please note that `ConfigureAwait` and `GetAwaiter` are basically the same - the latter can use the default configuration.

```
public class MyAwaitable
{
    private volatile bool completed;
    private volatile int result;
    private Action continuation;

    public bool IsCompleted => completed;

    public int Result => RunToCompletionAndGetResult();

    public MyAwaitable(int? result = null)
    {
        if (result.HasValue)
        {
            completed = true;
            this.result = result.Value;
        }
    }

    public void Finish(int result)
    {
        if (completed)
            return;
        completed = true;
        this.result = result;

        continuation?.Invoke();
    }

    public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter() => ConfigureAwait(true);

    public MyAwaiter ConfigureAwait(bool captureContext)
        => new MyAwaiter(this, captureContext);

    internal void ScheduleContinuation(Action action) => continuation += action;

    internal int RunToCompletionAndGetResult()
    {
        var wait = new SpinWait();
        while (!completed)
            wait.SpinOnce();
        return result;
    }
}
```

**3. The awaiter**

`OnCompleted` now does not execute the continuation (unlike the examples I investigated) but registers it for later by calling `MyAwaitable.ScheduleContinuation`.

Secondly, please note that now the awaiter also has a `GetAwaiter` method that just returns itself. This is needed for the `await myAwaitable.ConfigureAwait(bool)` usage.

```
public class MyAwaiter : INotifyCompletion
{
    private readonly MyAwaitable awaitable;
    private readonly bool captureContext;

    public MyAwaiter(MyAwaitable awaitable, bool captureContext)
    {
        this.awaitable = awaitable;
        this.captureContext = captureContext;
    }

    public MyAwaiter GetAwaiter() => this;

    public bool IsCompleted => awaitable.IsCompleted;

    public int GetResult() => awaitable.RunToCompletionAndGetResult();

    public void OnCompleted(Action continuation)
    {
        var capturedContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        awaitable.ScheduleContinuation(() =>
        {
            if (captureContext && capturedContext != null)
                capturedContext.Post(_ => continuation(), null);
            else
                continuation();
        });
    }
}
```